# Passing array of address to Google Maps to get latitude and longitude

Tags: php, google-maps

I am using google map api to get lat/long for address, It works fine when I pass single address to map api, but now I have array of addresses and I want to lat/long for all addresses from array using single api call. Please suggest if this possible.

Note: Want to achieve this in PHP.

Comment: stackoverflow is not a 'code mill' What have you tried, can you show us your code and where the issue is that you are facing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to geocode a batch of addresses with only one API call. This is by design. For geocoding batches of addresses, using server side geocoding is recommended. If the reason you are trying to get an array of addresses geocoded with one call is due to you wanting to conserve your quota, I'd recommend looking at the article on optimizing quota usage here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/geocoding-strategies

I hope this helps!